# How to disable on delete cascade in DB2 LUW

Tags: sql, db2, db2-luw

I have 11 tables which has parent-child relationship and i wanted to delete around 3.27 billion (marked as D in parent most table) records out of 21 billion (Total count). I tried deleting from Child to parent and all my child most (infant) tables are deleted but now when i came one level up and try deleting from parent table its scanning my entire child table even though there is no matching records to delete. Is there a way i can disable ON-Delete cascade and foreign key drop on the go.

Comment: Drop the corresponding foreign key constraint.

Comment: It looks you don't have a proper index in the child table that matches your FK.  If you would the child table-scan would be avoided.